# How to configure Maven so that a plugin in an upstream artifact is executed in the downstream project

Tags: maven

Project A requires the Enforcer Plugin to run to verify that a particular environment is in place during the building of the artifact. Project A is deployed in the normal manner to Maven Central.

Project B, which is entirely separate, depends on Project A and has no knowledge of the Enforcer Plugin used in Project A.

Is there a way to ensure that the Enforcer Plugin present in Project A's POM is executed during the build of Project B, without Project B having to do any special configuration outside of the usual dependency declaration?

The configuration in Project A can be as esoteric as necessary to make it work. Project B cannot be given special instructions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your constraints: No, it's not possible.

The only way to make this work is by [making A the parent project of B](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance) or by moving this check into a new parent POM which both A and B inherit from.

But as long as you refuse to change B's setup, it can't be done.

Comment: Yeah, I thought as much. Good to have it confirmed, though.